# Autofac dynamic invocation with Func and Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, service-locator

Providing that I have a class as follows

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(string someTitle, IFooService fooService)
    { 
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

I know that I can instantiate it like this using DI and autofac

```
public class Bar
{
    public Bar(Func < string, IFooService, Foo > foo, IFooService fooService)
    {
        var foo = foo("some string", fooService);
    }
}
```

but I'm wondering if there's any way for `Bar` to not have to know anything about `IFooService`? I'd like to not have to inject IFooService into Bar just to satisfy the func.

Essentially something like this

```
// pseudo code - don't use
public class Bar
{
    public Bar(Func < string, Foo > foo)
    {
        var foo = foo("some string");
    }
}
```

What I'm really trying to do in my app is remove all instances of Service Location, and rely solely on Dependency Injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's where you use factories for:

```
public interface IFooFactory
{
    Foo CreateFoo(string value);
}
```

And bar can simply depend on `IFooFactory`.

The implementation can look as follows:

```
public class FooFactory : IFooFactory
{
    private readonly IFooService fooService;

    public FooFactory(IFooService fooService)
    { 
        this.fooService = fooService;
    }

    public Foo CreateFoo(string value)
    {
        return new Foo(value, this.fooService);
    }
}
```

But the given string seems like a runtime value, i.e. a value that changes from request to request or from call to call. Prevent mixing runtime values with design time dependencies as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23364005/264697), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22487207/264697) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22371672/264697). Instead, pass the runtime value as method argument to the `Foo` methods you are calling. That will completely remove the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Autofac should be able to do exactly what you want by using [the `Func<T>` implicit relationship](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html).

Here is a small repro showing how you can omit the `IFooService` parameter in the `Func<T>` and as long as the other dependencies can be resolved by Autofac, you're good to go.

Sample types that do some crazy work...

```
public class Bar
{
    private Foo _foo;

    // This constructor looks like what you're aiming for...
    public Bar(Func<string, Foo> factory)
    {
        this._foo = factory("title");
    }

    public void ShowMeCoolStuff()
    {
        this._foo.DoWork();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    private string _title;
    private IFooService _service;

    // The Foo class takes the title AND an IFooService...
    public Foo(string title, IFooService service)
    {
        this._title = title;
        this._service = service;
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo title = {0}", this._title);
        this._service.DoMoreWork();
    }
}

public interface IFooService
{
    void DoMoreWork();
}

public class FooService : IFooService
{
    public void DoMoreWork()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("FooService doing more work.");
    }
}
```

When you register, make sure all the dependencies are registered - `Foo`, `Bar`, something implementing `IFooService`:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<Foo>();
builder.RegisterType<Bar>();
builder.RegisterType<FooService>().As<IFooService>();
var container = builder.Build();
```

When you resolve, everything chains down the line. This resolution...

```
var bar = container.Resolve<Bar>();
bar.ShowMeCoolStuff();
```

...will yield the following console output:

```
Foo title = title
FooService doing more work.
```

[There is fairly robust documentation with examples over on the Autofac site.](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html)